# what's the meaning of "It is generally held that"?

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of "It is generally held that"?

e.g. 
It is generally held that already during this period Egypt was losing some of its power and dominance

Answer (score 3):

It means that among the people who claim to know something about the subject, the most widely accepted theory is that which is "generally held".

So:

> It is generally held that already during this period Egypt was losing some of its power and dominance.

Means

> Most Egyptologists agree that during this period Egypt was losing some of its power and dominance.

Quite often this construction is used to introduce a *conflicting* idea that actually contradicts the generally held belief or conviction. After your sentence, one could write something like:

> However, the results of our new research show that Egypt may have been shifting its focus into a different geographical area, and thereby effectively expanding its power.

Answer (score 2):

The verb  'to hold' has a vast range of uses. It would be worth looking, if you have access, at the OED entry.

As well as it being generally 'held', as explained in the answer from @oerkelens, things can also be specifically held.

One will often, for example, see in a a report on a court judgement that 'It was held that...'. It means that the judge(s) determined, after due consideration, that the law was such and such. Here is an account (from Wikipedia) of one of the most famous judgments in English legal history, the 1932 case of Donaghue v Stevenson, which established the principle of commercial negligence.

Note how 'The House of Lords' (meaning the judicial committee of the House, sitting as a supreme court of appeal) **held** that the manufacturer was negligent.

> Donoghue v Stevenson [1932] UKHL 100 is a foundational case in Scots
>   delict law and English tort law by the House of Lords. It created the
>   modern concept of negligence, by setting out general principles
>   whereby one person would owe another person a duty of care.
>
> Also known as the "Paisley snail"[5][6] or "snail in the bottle" case,
>   the facts involved Mrs Donoghue drinking a bottle of ginger beer in a
>   café in Paisley, Renfrewshire. A dead snail was in the bottle. She
>   fell ill, and she sued the ginger beer manufacturer, Mr Stevenson. The
>   House of Lords held that the manufacturer owed a duty of care to her,
>   which was breached, because it was reasonably foreseeable that failure
>   to ensure the product's safety would lead to harm of consumers.

'Hold' in this sense is not only applicable in law. One might well overhear someone saying 'My grandmother always held that fresh air cured anything'.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "it"by "opinion", then you get: The opinion is generally held + that-clause.

Answer (score 0):

It simply means *most people think,* or, *most knowlegeable people think*, but because *most people think* doesn't sound academic or formal, this expression, using the passive voice, has arisen.

It suggests that the writer acknowledges there are alternative, less consensual theories but he/she is not going to dwell on that debate because it is not his/her purpose.